# Count columns by condition

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column (A) that contains a series of dates in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`. I want to run a count to return how many of them were in 2013.

Is this possible?

I tried using this formula, but it didn't work:

```
=COUNTIF (ARRAYFORMULA ( LEFT (C:C, 4)), "2013")
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the solution provided by OnenOnlyWalter, here's another formula:

```
=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(YEAR(A:A)),"2013")
```

The `YEAR` function simply returns the year in 4 digits. The `ARRAYFORMULA` will just take on the complete column and the `COUNTIF` will finish it off by counting the occurrences.

If you're using a header, then you can adjust the above formula like this:

```
=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(YEAR(A2:A)),"2013")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the right idea but the formula needs a little tweaking.

Try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF((RIGHT(TEXT(C:C,""),4)),"2013"))
```

Some things to point out:
- For a `MM/DD/YYYY` format, you need to take the right character, not left
- The cell contents for dates are not strings, so you need to use `TEXT()` to convert the dates

This worked on my test sheet, let me know if it works for you or if I need to tweak it a bit.